# GTK+3 widget maximum width/height

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtk#

With GTK+3, either via CSS or code, how can I set a specific size for a widget, such that the widget remains that size (e.g. regardless of content), when the widget is within a Fixed?

For example, FontButton will expand beyond its WidthRequest if the Font Description it displays is longer than the WidthRequest. This behaviour makes it very difficult to predict where the widget size will eventually end up and thus to plan where other widgets on a form should be positioned on a Fixed.

I've tried trawling the libraries and CSS properties but I've not found anything that prevents widget resizing beyond a fixed width.

Comment: Questions like this come up regularly. Number one: you shouldn't be using a Fixed unless you really know what you are doing. Number two: why are you limiting the size? So that begs the question - what are you actually trying to do? Explain what this app is supposed to do, and somebody probably will find a better widget / UI design.

Comment: Humm, ok thanks. I had a feeling an answer like this might come. I'm converting an app that is GTK2 to GTK3, with the previous app leveraging Fixed (to good effect visually, no resizing etc.). I think my strategy here will be to replace the majority of them with some other layout container that makes sense, but I'm staring down quite a bit of work there. Thanks for your response!

Comment: If it's an open source app, could you link it back here?

Comment: Sure, thanks for your help. Latest is here https://continuity.kiwi.nz/Downloads/Continuity%20v22.10-313%20Source.zip I've started Grid-ifying everything now anyway and managed to plough a fair way through.